# NodeJs Mongoose passing parameters to post findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

I want to use post findOneAndUpdate middlewares to save a log data of all my mongoose model changes.

> > I use findOneAndUpdate in three places:
>
> ```
>  - Update Model's data
>  - change Model status
>  - archive / restore Model
> ```

So when I use the post findOneAndUpdate middlewares, I want to know which one of the three findOneAndUpdate was executed.

Is there a way to pass parameters from findOneAndUpdate to post findOneAndUpdate middlewares?

Here is my code:

**controller**: invoices.js

```
    update: function (request, response, next) {
    //checking general invoice information
    request.checkBody(typeValidationSchema);
    request.getValidationResult().then(function(result) {
        if (!result.isEmpty()) return response.apiError(result.array());
        else {
            Invoice.findOneAndUpdate({
                _id: request.params.invoiceId,
                createdBy: request.user._id
            }, request.body, {'new': true, 'runValidators': true}).exec(function (error, invoice) {
                if (error) response.apiError(error);
                if (!invoice) return response.apiNotFound();
                else return response.apiResponse(invoice);
            });
        }
    });
},
```

**Model Schema**: invoice.js

```
InvoiceSchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(doc) {
// I want to get her some variables passed from controller findOneAndUpdate
});
```

Comment: There is surely a way but could you show your code ?

Comment: yes, it is possible!!! you can use `console.log` to track the callback result...

Comment: @TGrif I added my code, thank you.

Comment: @AmulyaKashyap Can you elaborate your comment please.